# Как отсортировать изображения с разным размером и разместить их в квадрат? (пример ниже)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

Есть группа изображений, которые нужно разместить в разные разделы галереи. Они разного размера, но разместить их нужно в квадрат или прямоугольников + на divах есть ховер-текст. Как такое реализовать на jquery или может есть маленькая библиотека специально для таких целей? Заранее спасибо.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Все, нашел! Если кому надо ищите в поисковике по запросу
"jquery filter portfolio gallery"
и получаете куча отличных примеров.

а также, нарветесь на саму библиотечку https://isotope.metafizzy.co/